# Google admob and Play Store account

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, ads, admob

My android app and my admob account are different accounts. (For example: My play store account is one gmail com and admob account is two gmail com)

My question is can I add admob ads to my application now?
In this case I added ads to app but don't show ads in any devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add admob ads to your application, there is no problem with that. It would be better if you switch to using one account though, but it is only for your comfort, you could do it with two account too.

Comment: Thank you. I added admob to application but don't show ads any device. I added test device and its okay. Test ads working . But real ads is not showing

Comment: So you have changed only the ad ID and nothing more? In your admob account, can you see the particular ad you are using in your application is enabled? Can you post some code on how you show ads exactly? Also check this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start